# PHP code parse error, maybe just wrong formating

Tags: php, html-table, format

I am trying to show images in my table which shows through the PHP code, however it gives me an error and I can't figure out where.

```
echo '<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="description"> . "<img src='images/" . $product_data["mainImageThumbnail"] . "' alt='Product image' />
    <p><a href="main.php?prodid=' . $product["product_id"] . '">' . $product["name"] . '</a>
    <br /> $products_data["description"] </p>
    <a href="#">Remove</a>
    </td> ';
```

Comment: `<img src='images/"` you have a single quote just after `src=` it should be a `"`. Didn't continue looking it is always better to always keep html out of php. use only php where you want like `<?php echo $product_data["mainImageThumbnail"];?>` inside the html

Comment: Please check your single and double quotes.They are all aligned wrong

Comment: If you get an error, give the error message as well (and also search for that error message, at least in the [PHP Error Reference we have on site](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456))

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the concatenation of PHP with HTML

```
echo '<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="description">
<img src="images/' . $product_data["mainImageThumbnail"] . '" alt="Product image" />
<p><a href="main.php?prodid=' . $product["product_id"] . '">' . $product["name"] . '</a>
<br />'. $products_data["description"] .'</p>
<a href="#">Remove</a>
</td> ';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" class="description">
        <img src="images/' . $product_data["mainImageThumbnail"] . '" alt="Product image"/>
        <p>
            <a href="main.php?prodid=' . $product["product_id"] . '">' . $product["name"] . '</a>
            <br/>' .
            $products_data["description"] . '
        </p>
    <a href="#">Remove</a>
</td> ';
```